# Logarithm of a non-diagonalizable matrix

Tags: matrices, jordan-normal-form, matrix-exponential

I am trying to find a matrix X such that

$$ e^X = \left(
    \begin{matrix}
    0 & 2021 & 0  & ... & ... & ... & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 2020  & ... & ... & ... & 0\\
    0 & 0 & ... & ... & ... & ... & 0\\
0 & 0 & ... & ... & ... & ... & 0\\
0 & 0 & ... & ... & ... & 3 & 0\\
0 & 0 & ... & ... & ... & 0 & 2\\
1 & 0 & ... & ... & ... & ... & 0\\
\\
    \end{matrix}\right)
$$

Which means I will need to find the log of a non-diagonalizable matrix. I know I can typically find the Jordan form of the matrix, but this one is so large, it seems very difficult. I also know the MacLaurin series for ln(X), but the matrix is not nilpotent, so the series is infinite.

I am not sure if I'm missing something in my conclusions about Jordan form and MacLaurin series. Can anyone help me identify the best way to go about this?

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. – For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: This matrix is diagonalizable (and invertible), and you can actually find the eigenvalues & eigenvectors explicitly. Don't write any determinants, just write down explicitly the equation that the components of an eigenvector should satisfy, and solve it.

Comment: Okay, I tried writing it out as Av = λv, to see if the eigenvalues were obvious, but there doesn't seem to be a simple solution. The eigenvalues are very complicated, I think, and I'm not sure how to find them.

Comment: One quick observation: if the entries of an eigenvector of $e^X$ are $x_1, \ldots, x_{2021}$ and the eigenvalue is $\lambda$, then $\lambda x_1 = 2021 x_2$, $\lambda x_2 = 2020 x_3$, $\lambda x_3 = 2019 x_4, \ldots, \lambda x_{2020} = 2 x_{2021}, \lambda x_{2021} = x_1$. Multiplying these equations together and dividing out a factor of $x_1 x_2 \cdots x_{2021}$ gives $\lambda^{2021} = 2021!$.

Comment: Ohhh, I see now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I will outline the essential procedure below. Define analogously an $n\times n$ matrix $A$. Let $r=(n!)^{1/n}$ and $D=\operatorname{diag}\left(\frac{r^{n}}{n!},\frac{r^{n-1}}{(n-1)!},\ldots,\frac{r^{2}}{2!},r\right)$. Then $A$ is diagonally similar to $r$ times a circulant permutation matrix:
$$
DAD^{-1}=rC:=r\pmatrix{0&1\\ &0&1\\ &&\ddots&\ddots\\ &&&0&1\\ 1&&&&0}.
$$
Hence one can take $\log(A)$ as $D^{-1}\log(rC)D=\log(r)I+D^{-1}\log(C)D$ and the problem boils down to finding a matrix logarithm of the circulant permutation matrix $C$.

$C$ is the companion matrix of the characteristic polynomial $x^n-1$. Its eigenvalues are therefore $\omega^k$ for $k=0,1,\ldots,n-1$, where $\omega=\exp(2\pi i/n)$ is a primitive $n$-th root of unity. So, $C$ has not any negative eigenvalue when $n$ is odd and it has exactly one negative eigenvalue when $n$ is even. It follows that $C$ has a **real** matrix logarithm if and only if $n$ is odd.

The eigen structures of circulant matrices are well-known. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix) for a brief description. In particular, $C=U\operatorname{diag}(1,\omega,\omega^2,\ldots,\omega^{n-1})U^\ast$, where $U$ is the unitary [DFT matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFT_matrix) of order $n$. Therefore one can always take
$$
\log(C)=U\operatorname{diag}\left(0,\frac{2\pi i}{n},\frac{4\pi i}{n},\ldots,\frac{2(n-1)\pi i}{n}\right)U^\ast
$$
to obtain a complex logarithm of $C$.

When $n$ is odd (as in your case, where $n=2021$), in order to obtain a real logarithm, we may express the eigenvalues
$$
1,\omega,\omega^2,\ldots,\omega^{(n-1)/2},\omega^{(n+1)/2},\ldots,\omega^{n-2},\omega^{n-1}
$$
as
$$
1,\omega,\omega^2,\ldots,\omega^{(n-1)/2},\overline{\omega}^{(n-1)/2},\ldots,\overline{\omega}^2,\overline{\omega}
$$
and take
$$
\log(C)=U\operatorname{diag}\left(0,\frac{2\pi i}{n},\frac{4\pi i}{n},\ldots,\frac{(n-1)\pi i}{n},\frac{-(n-1)\pi i}{n},\ldots,\frac{-4\pi i}{n},\frac{-2\pi i}{n}\right)U^\ast.
$$
Then $\log(C)$ will be a weighted sum of outer products of eigenvectors where non-real terms appear in conjugate pairs. Hence it is a real matrix.